# USB internal control to on/off a pc fan molex circuit

Tags: power-supply, usb, control, fan, motherboard

I am new to electronic circuits so I might not have the correct nomenclature for some items.

- Description:

  I have 3 high power 12V PC fans (NON PWM) connected to a hub that draw power from MOLEX connector. They can't be controlled by any means except with a on / off IR remote coming with the hub (No hard switches).
  They draw some high current. They can't be powered over 5V USB directly.
- Issue:

  I need advice for simple circuit idea (without Arduino) to connect a USB from Motherboard to control the on/off of these fans (while drawing full power from Molex).

  i.e. when the motherboard is powered off, the fans are turned off and when i switch pc on again they turn on automatically (without having to remove the molex connection / using remote every-time i try to switch them off).

Comment: I am confused. Which "molex"? The one that comes from PC PSU? Or elsewhere? When PC is "soft-OFF", 12 V is also OFF so the fans won't spin. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an NPN transistor with the base connected to the 5V (by 1k resistor) coming from the USB, collector connected to the negative terminal of the fan and emitter connected to ground. This way whenever the usb gets power the fan will power on (providing 12v is present)

This configuration:

[image: NPN switch]

Comment: Thanks alot. Excuse my shallow knowledge in electronics. But i have questions. First: the 1k resistor with the base will connect to which ( +ve or -ve) wire of the usb. and where will the other remaining wire connect to. second: confirm if i get this right "the +ve from the fan will connect to the +ve from the molex. Where does the -ve of the molex connect to ?

Comment: No problem, the base of the transistor will connect to a 1k resistor, the 1k resistor will then connect to the +ve (5v) wire of the usb connector. the +ve of the fan will connect to the +ve of the molex connector (12v) and the -ve will connect to the collector of the transistor. the emitter of the transistor will then connect to the -ve of the molex (ground)

Comment: youll need to spec the transistor to suite, a bc182l will go up to 100mA but you probably need more than that, any idea what power / current requirements the fans have?

Comment: 3 fans with 0.5 A each, we can assume the hub control taking 0.1 A. Hence we could say 1.6A in total.

Comment: So a 500mA capable part should be good for overhead (1 on each fan) youll also need a flywheel diode across the fan as its an inductive load. Have a look here, seems to be exactly what you need https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219897

Comment: That was very Helpful. Learnt some good stuff. Thanks alot for ur effort.

Comment: This solution won't work on most desktop PC. Most desktop PC have the VBUS power switched from main +5V rail to standby +5VSB rail when PC is put to OFF state. So the VBUS is always ON.